# How do I return Eloquent models using relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `queue` class that has multiple `rules`.  I've set up my classes like so:

```
class Queue extends Eloquent {

    function rules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Rule');
    }
}

class Rule extends Eloquent {

    function queue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Queue');
    }

    function displayInfo()
    {
        echo "Title: ".$this->title;
    }

}
```

I want to get all the rules that belong to a `queue` and display their info but when I try this:

```
$rules = $queue->rules;
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $rule->displayInfo();
}
```

I get the following exception:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::displayInfo()`

Is there any way to get back the actually Eloquent model representations of a rule with a relationship?

Comment: Can you post the code that populated your `$queue` variable?

Comment: $queue = Queue::find($id);

Comment: What do you get for `echo gettype($rule);` ?

Comment: I get `Rule`.  I can even use `$rule->id` and get the correct answer but I can't use my function. I'm trying to contain as much logic as possible in the model instead of having lots of ifs and fors in my view.

Comment: What does this produce `Rule::first()->displayInfo()` ?

Comment: Same thing. If I do `get_class($rule->first())` I get `Rule` but I still can't call `displayInfo()`

Comment: Do you get the same error? Your error says that you're trying to call it on the Builder, but it's a model. Double check your error.

Comment: It is the same error.  That's the confusing thing for me too, since all signs point to it being a model until I try to call a function from it.  Am I somehow accessing an underlying object?

Comment: Also, in your error it says that you're trying to call `displayRow`, but in the code you pasted the method name is `displayInfo`. Typo?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Looks like I must have had a typo in my Rule class.  I just scrapped it and started over and it works fine now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the type of **$rules** ( object or array ).

Comment: It is an object. The class is Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.

Answer (score 0):

On Collections you should use the built-in helpers, as described here:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

You can then use:

```
$rules = $queue->rules->each(function($rule)
{
    return $rule->displayInfo();
});
```